# How to write unittest for @task decorated Airflow tasks?

Tags: airflow, python-unittest, airflow-taskflow

I am trying to write unittests for some of the tasks built with [Airflow TaskFlow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html). I tried multiple approaches for example, by creating a dagrun or only running the task function but nothing is helping.

Here is a task where I download a file from S3, there is more stuff going on but I removed that for this example.

```
@task()
def updates_process(files):
    context = get_current_context()
    try:
        updates_file_path = utils.download_file_from_s3_bucket(files.get("updates_file"))
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        log.error(e)
        return

    # Do something else
```

Now I was trying to write a test case where I can check this except clause. Following is one the example I started with

```
class TestAccountLinkUpdatesProcess(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.log")
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.get_current_context")
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.utils.download_file_from_s3_bucket")
    def test_file_not_found_error(self, download_file_from_s3_bucket, get_current_context, log):
        download_file_from_s3_bucket.side_effect = FileNotFoundError
        task = account_link_updates_process({"updates_file": "path/to/file.csv"})
        get_current_context.assert_called_once()
        log.error.assert_called_once()
```

I also tried by creating a dagrun as shown in the [example here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#unit-tests) in docs and fetching the task from the dagrun but that also didin't help.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling to do this myself, but I found that [the decorated tasks have a `.function` parameter](https://github.dev/apache/airflow/blob/be7cb1e837b875f44fcf7903329755245dd02dc3/airflow/decorators/base.py#L522).

You can then use `Task.function()` to call the actual function. Using your example:

```py
class TestAccountLinkUpdatesProcess(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.log")
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.get_current_context")
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.utils.download_file_from_s3_bucket")
    def test_file_not_found_error(self, download_file_from_s3_bucket, get_current_context, log):
        download_file_from_s3_bucket.side_effect = FileNotFoundError
        task = dags.delta_load.updates.updates_process
        # Call the function for testing
        task.function({"updates_file": "path/to/file.csv"})
        get_current_context.assert_called_once()
        log.error.assert_called_once()
```

This prevents you from having to set up any of the DAG infrastructure and just run the python function as intended!

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me. I got error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'function'. Upon some investigation I can use `task.__wrapped__()` the way you mentioned.

Comment: `.function` worked for me too. So in your example it would be `assert updates_process.function(["file1", "file2", ...])`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could figure out. Not sure if this is the right thing but it works.

```
class TestAccountLinkUpdatesProcess(TestCase):
    TASK_ID = "updates_process"

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.dag = dag_delta_load()

    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.log")
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.get_current_context")
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.utils.download_file_from_s3_bucket")
    def test_file_not_found_error(self, download_file_from_s3_bucket, get_current_context, log):
        download_file_from_s3_bucket.side_effect = FileNotFoundError
        task = self.dag.get_task(task_id=self.TASK_ID)
        task.op_args = [{"updates_file": "file.csv"}]
        task.execute(context={})
        log.error.assert_called_once()
```

**UPDATE:** Based on the answer of @AetherUnbound I did some investigation and found that we can use `task.__wrapped__()` to call the actual python function.

```
class TestAccountLinkUpdatesProcess(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.log")
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.get_current_context")
    @mock.patch("dags.delta_load.updates.utils.download_file_from_s3_bucket")
    def test_file_not_found_error(self, download_file_from_s3_bucket, get_current_context, log):
        download_file_from_s3_bucket.side_effect = FileNotFoundError
        update_process.__wrapped__({"updates_file": "file.csv"})
        log.error.assert_called_once()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run the dag as part of your unit tests, and are finding it difficult to get access to the **actual dag itself** due to the Airflow Taskflow API decorators, you can do something like this in your tests:

```
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_something(self):

        dags = []
        real_dag_enter = DAG.__enter__

        def fake_dag_enter(dag):
            # Whenever a dag gets created (behind the scenes),
            # DAG.__enter__(self) gets called - you can use this
            # to keep a list of dags that get created so that
            # you can run unit tests on them.

            dags.append(dag)

            return real_dag_enter(self=dag)

        with patch.object(DAG, "__enter__", new=fake_dag_enter):

            for dag in dags:

                # Run your dag here, and assert
                # that it does what it's supposed to.
                #
                # (I have a utility class that loops through the
                # tasks in the dag and executes each one.)
```